# undefined method email for nil:Nilclass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have users through devise. So that is my user model.

I have home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My log in is fine. My index page works fine.

My show page to show logged in user's tweets...

```
<h1>Profile Page for <%= @user.email %></h1>
  <p><%= @user.email %></p>
  <% @user.tweets.each do |tweet| %>
<p><%= tweet.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

when I try to go to localhost:3000/users/1

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass (error on first line)
```

My routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/show'
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'home#index'

  match 'users/:id' => 'home#show', via: :get


end
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's a little bit strange, since you do have `@user` variable defined in your controller. Where does this error come from? Which specific line?

Comment: Comes from first line. <h1>Profile Page for <%= @user.email %></h1>

Comment: Silly question: Are you sure you saved your `home_controller.rb` file?

Comment: Yup. Again just in case. NoMethodError in Home#show...

Comment: would you output your log/development.log around that error? It seems like your @user is set to nil when it tries to use it in view.

Comment: maybe its easier than you think. Maybe there is no user with id = 1. Try to debug your method show with `pry` or smth and play with it.

Comment: Have you verified that there is a user in the DB with an id of 1?

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I restarted server and now it works! :/ Sorry!

Comment: Was it run in production env? Or was `config.cache_classes` set to `true`?

@sonic no record of id = 1 would result in `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` with this code.

Comment: @MarekLipka hmm so do you mean that @user would return `RecordNotFound` instead of `Nil` ?

Comment: No, I mean `User.find(some_non_existant_id)` raises an error of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` class.